# Is there anything faster than regex for matching a whole word?

Tags: c#, regex, match, contains

**EDIT**:

My original question was asking whether anything could ever be faster than regex for matching a whole word. I have added my code, and have run several tests. The details are below

My sample matching string (from *The Old Man And The Sea*)

*He was an old man who fished alone in a skiff in the Gulf Stream and he had gone eighty-four days now without taking a fish. In the first forty days a boy had been with him. But after forty days without a fish the boy’s parents had told him that the old man was now definitely and finally salao, which is the worst form of unlucky, and the boy had gone at their orders in another boat which caught three good fish the first week*

Here's my regex

```
"(\b(cod|tuna|mackerel|plaice|haddock|salmon|prawns|shrimp|fishcake|halibut|sole|eel|anchovy|anchovies|sardine|herring|bonito|whiting|seabass|carp|crab|flounder|pollock|mullet|ray|ray wings|clam|mussel|scallop)(s?)\b)"
```

Here's my first matching attempt without regex

```
public static words = "cod|tuna|mackerel|plaice|haddock|salmon|prawns|shrimp|fishcake|halibut|sole|eel|anchovy|anchovies|sardine|herring|bonito|whiting|seabass|carp|crab|flounder|pollock|mullet|ray|ray wings|clam|mussel|scallop";

public static bool MatchBySplitting(string sentence)
{
    string[] sentence_words = sentence.Split(',','.',' ',';','-');
    string[] match_words = words.Split('|'); 

    foreach(string w in sentence_words)
    {
        foreach(string m in match_words)
        {
            if(m == w)
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Running 5000 iterations of each:

- **Regex Matching:** 250-300 ms
- **MatchBySplitting:** 250-350 ms, a comparable time to the regex.

However, if I shorten my matching string to just the first line, my results change

*He was an old man who fished alone in a skiff in the Gulf Stream and he had gone eighty-four days now without taking a fish.*

The regex stays about the same, but `MatchBySplitting` speeds up a lot:

- **Regex Matching:** 220-260 ms
- **MatchBySplitting:** 50-150 ms - Faster than regex.

If I then start messing with the classics, and insert a word that *will* match

*He was an old man who fished alone in a skiff in the Gulf Stream and he had gone eighty-four days now without taking a fish. Then on the eighty fifth day, he caught a tuna. the end*

- **Regex Matching:** 170-300 ms
- **MatchBySplitting:** 100-200 ms - Faster than regex.

I think I've answered my own question here. My custom matching method seems to be equal to or faster than regex in most cases.

However, I haven't covered all word boundaries in my code (!?) so it may slow down a little if I add those in.

Comment: This depends on both your regex string and also the regex implementation, I suppose.

Comment: By your own assertion that by fiddling with both you were able to make one eclipse the other in speed and then vice-versa, the obvious answer is "it depends."

Comment: If you include your code, this would be a great candidate for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Although you can't give any definitive answer without seeing the 2 versions of the code, this kind of problem - Unless you only expect a few different word boundaries so you could easily code it in - seems much more suited to regex in my opinion.

Comment: Don't forget to check for the cases where it's the first or last word in the string (or both), so there's no word boundary character.

Comment: regex is generally slower for simple queries and this isn't a simple query so regex should be faster.

Comment: Is better to do somethig that is a little bit slower, but more readable.

Comment: You could move `string[] match_words = words.Split('|'); ` out of your function too and make that a one time hit.

Answer (score 2):

Try making a compiled regex, like this:

```
static readonly Regex CornRegex = new Regex("\b(corn)\b", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

This will actually generate and compile a method that contains the assembly instructions needed to match that regex. It should be very fast, comparable to writing your own custom function that loops over the individual characters.

Comment: Thanks john, unfortunately my code is for Windows phone which doesn't support compiled regex

Comment: There is a way to compile a regex to an assembly... `Regex.CompileToAssembly`. You could try to compile your regex to a assembly in a windows environment, and then use it on the phone... I'm not sure this will work, but it might!

Comment: these matches are based on user input params, so I can't pre-compile either.