# Which would be faster -- regex matching or my own match function?

Tags: java, android, regex, algorithm

I am developing an Android App called Smart Call Blocker which lets you enter a regex pattern and then retrieves incoming phone numbers and performs a match and then allows/rejects the call depending on whether the match was successful or not.

The pattern that a user enters is supposed to allow:

```
either a digit, or a dot (meaning don't care the digit at this position), 
or a range (e.g. [3-7]), or a set of digits (e.g. [2, 5, 8])
```

Now I have written code to manually compare the incoming phone number digit by digit with respect to the pattern and allow/reject a call accordingly. It is running in linear time (number of comparisons equal to the number of digits in the phone number).

Which should be faster and lighter for an android app?

1. The manual method written by me.
2. The regex library using its own Pattern.compile() and matches() etc methods.

And why and how?

**EDIT:**

I have pasted the code [here](http://pastebin.com/YRCc4bmf). I am unable to do a proper benchmarking for the android OS, although I can do an execution time comparison on the two said ways as normal java programs on my system. But I don't think there would be any conclusion that can be made by just seeing the runtime of these programs on system than when ran on actual android device.

Comment: You could make use of Google's libphonenumber for a start

Comment: The best way to really find out is to do your own benchmarking. It may be that your code is faster, as regex has a wider range of capabilities, and it could be more memory-consuming. Or maybe your code is not so optimal and regex is better. Or even that there is no significant difference. Since you did not share your code, no one can really answer this. But still, doing your own benchmark is the best approach

Comment: @IvayloSlavov, even I was assuming that but then I saw this answer and I was a bit confused. http://stackoverflow.com/a/22304634/996565
And I am adding my code, it is just character by character comparisons as I have mentioned.

Comment: I would recommend using a benchmark framework to make your tests like junit benchmark. But then, you might note that your algorithl only saved milliseconds and that, after all, you should keep using regex (at least from what I know).

Comment: Keep in mind that compiling the regex at runtime may not be very efficient (especially for slower mobile devices). If the users create the regex, you will need to compile it at runtime. Perhaps you will also have to validate if it is proper regex, to avoid problems. If users create a bad (but valid) regex, they could crash the app by creating and endless match loop or other issue. If that is not an overhead for you, or you are certain the regex is safely created, it is acceptable. But, beware of user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this isn't a good SO question because there's no way to provide references or test my answer with what you've given.  So some answers based on theory:

> Which should be faster and lighter for an android app?

Your code *should* be faster. Two reasons:

1. It is "precompiled."  The regex matcher compiles the pattern into an internal code of some kind (a bytecode or tree).  This takes time.  Your code runs with no such overhead.
2. Most regex matchers - including the Java library's - use a general branch and bound search algorithm.  Even if searching is never necessary (it always branches correctly), the capability to search introduces some small overhead.

So if your code is running slower than an equivalent regex, your code is not good.  There is one caveat:  In Android your code is probably written in Java, I am assuming the Android regex library is still Java code.  It was last time I wrote to Android, but that's been several versions ago.  The Android Java compiler is not yet as good as the native gcc. So if some optimization has been added, you might have to re-implement your code natively to do better than a regex.

**Very important caveat and educated guess:** Reading patterns from the file and compiling (if using regexes) should be done only once during app start-up.  If you do this, the speed difference between your code and the regex method will be so tiny that it won't make a difference.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the "only once during startup" tip.